# Getting 500 error when trying to convert textile field to Wygwam field

Tags: wygwam

I am trying to convert a field type from a textarea with textile formatting to use Wygwam.  I am getting a long hang time and then a 500 server error.  The amount of articles using this field is over 1200, but if I change the field to wygwam without converting the textile the formatting is all messed up.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your php and apache logs. Sounds like the change is running out of resources... either memory, CPU or time? Increasing the problem resource/setting should help.